# Get the key value from a json in Java - JSON Parsing

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parsing, jackson

I have a json as below. I want to get mobile_number from this jsonObject.

json:-

```
{"id": "ABCD", "report": { "data": { "phone": { "mobile_number": 9876543210, "active": "Y", "content": null } } } }
```

I am doing it like this and it works fine but can someone help me with any other approach for it without getting every key.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject report = getJSONObjectFromJson(jsonObject, "report");
JSONObject data = getJSONObjectFromJson(jsonObject, "data");
JSONObject phone = getJSONObjectFromJson(data, "phone");
long mobileNumber = getLongFromJson(phone, "mobile_number");

private Long getLongFromJson(JSONObject object, String key){
    return (object !=null && object.has(key)) ? object.getLong(key) : null;
}

private JSONObject getJSONObjectFromJson(JSONObject object, String key){
    return (object !=null && object.has(key)) ? object.getJSONObject(key) : null;
}
```

Comment: You could use a json mapper as `gson` for example. In this case you only define objects with the properties you want to access and apply the parse method

Comment: There isn't a way to do it without traversing the tree, one way or another.

Comment: I think the value of `mobile_number` should be wrapped by double quotes because it may starts with `0` which makes your JSON string be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I've just dealing with the similar issue and decided to use JsonPath like this:

```
final DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
final Object read = jsonContext.read("$['report']['data']['phone']['mobile_number']");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jackson ObjectMapper.

```
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonString = "{\"id\": \"ABCD\", \"report\": { \"data\": { \"phone\": { \"mobile_number\": 9876543210, \"active\": \"Y\", \"content\": null } } } }";
            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

            JsonNode mobileNumber = rootNode.path("report").path("data").path("phone").path("mobile_number");
            System.out.println("Mobile Number: " + mobileNumber.longValue());

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are lot of ways to do it but everything leads eventually to traversing the tree.

So to conclude all the approaches,

```
1. **Convert string to JsonObject and traverse.** 

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject report = getJSONObjectFromJson(jsonObject, "report");
    JSONObject data = getJSONObjectFromJson(jsonObject, "data");
    JSONObject phone = getJSONObjectFromJson(data, "phone");
    long mobileNumber = getLongFromJson(phone, "mobile_number");
    
    private Long getLongFromJson(JSONObject object, String key){
        return (object !=null && object.has(key)) ? object.getLong(key) : null;
    }
    
    private JSONObject getJSONObjectFromJson(JSONObject object, String key){
        return (object !=null && object.has(key)) ? object.getJSONObject(key) : null;
    }

 2. **Using jackson objectMapper to get the JsonNode and then traverse.**

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode= mapper.readTree(json);
    JsonNode mobileNumber = jsonNode.path("report").path("data").path("phone").path("mobile_number");

 3. **Using gson jsonmapper to convert to map and then iterate the map.**

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("x").getJSONObject("Y").getJSONObject("z");
```

Another route would be to leverage the ***ObjectMapper***.